# Coding dummy variables and conditional statements in R

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am familiar with coding dummy variables in this way to use in regression analysis (example is from coding for region in panel data)

```
    dum1<-ifelse(var=="condition",1,0)
```

What I’m wondering is why when I attempt to code it this way

```
    if(variable=="condition"){dum1<-1} else {dum1<-0}
```

I get this:

```
Warning message: In if (variable == "condition") { : the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Can someone help explain this to me? Thanks

Comment: Check the many well written answers to get a better understanding of your error message.

Comment: You want `dum1 <- variable == "condition"`